# Bundler not installing private gem from git repo

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, bundler

I am having trouble creating a private gem, pushing it to a private git repo, and then USING that gem in my `Gemfile` via a `:git` reference.

The problem is that `bundler` (while giving no error) doesn't seem to install the gem for me.

I found that I can demonstrate this with any gem, not just mine.  So I'm going to demonstrate it using the 'colorize' gem since it is already on github and rubygems, and is a simple gem that has no dependencies.  Here is my test.rb file that uses the gem:

```
require 'colorize'
puts 'some blue text'.colorize(:blue)
```

**CASE ONE (this works):**

The Gemfile is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'colorize'
```

Bundle runs happily, and `ruby test.rb` outputs the blue text just fine.

I then run `gem uninstall colorize` to clean up before the next test.

**CASE TWO (fails):**

Now, I change the Gemfile to this:

```
#source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'colorize', :git => 'git@github.com:fazibear/colorize.git'
```

Note that I commented out the rubygems.org line to be sure I don't accidentally get the gem from rubygems.

Bundle again runs just fine, and can be seen to get the gem from the repo.  So far so good.  But now, `ruby test.rb` fails: `require cannot load 'colorize'`.  It would seem that the gem didn't get installed, and indeed if I run `gem uninstall colorize` to clean up, it says that colorize is not installed!

So what am I doing wrong here, or failing to understand?  I want to have the gem installed from a git repo, not rubygems, since the gem is a private gem.

Thanks,
-- Glenn

Comment: run `bundle exec ./test.rb`

Comment: has my answer been helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Of course the gem isn't installed in second case, that is correct, since it was removed. But when *bundler* clones a git repo, or to use a *path* key to create a gem, it doesn't use ruby's **gem** utility, and to know weither the gem is installed successfully you have just to run, and to see the path of the installed gem:

```
$ bundle show colorize
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-~.~.~@irb/gems/colorize-~.~.~
```

If case the gem isn't properly installed, you shell see:

```
Could not find gem 'colorize'.
```

And will have to issue `bundle install` again, and trap errors if any.

Since the *bundler* doesn't call the `gem` command, doesn't put the checked out gems from git repos or *GitHub* into common gem pull, and instead of it creates the gem itself inside its pull, and controls it. You should run your script using the *bundler* itself:

```
$ bundle exec ./test.rb
```

or

```
$ bundle exec ruby test.rb
```

Comment: -1 This is not what the OP is asking, he is unable to install the gem itself.

Comment: @ansh0l can you read the provided by author error `"require cannot load 'colorize'"`, and the text `Bundle again runs just fine,` from author's message? They say that install passed successfully. So you are incorrect.

Comment: I don't think so. There is no gem to be uninstalled in the second case, which means the gem wasn't installed. Anyway, I will wait for OP to respond on the question; will remove my downvote if I am wrong, or if he doesn't come back by tomorrow.

Comment: @ansh0l Of course the gem isn't installed in second case, that is correct. It was removed, but when *bundler* clones a git repo or to use `path` key to create a gem, it doesn't use ruby's `gem` utility. and to know weither the gem is installed successfully, you have to just run: `bundle show gem_name`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me your ssh connection to github is not setup properly.

Try doing a `ssh -T git@github.com` as suggested [here on github](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys), this will give you an error if things are misconfigured. Follow the steps mentioned in the link and then check again, things should work fine then. FWIW, I tried and was able to install the gem in this fashion.

If you were installing this gem on a server, run this command on the server itself.

An alternative to overcome this (the limitation of configuring ssh keys for each account to use `git@github.com` url in `:git`) is to instead use a `https` url (Check out [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-bundler/plUFBY6CkjA)); this however beats all the purpose of using ssh keys.